# Elasticsearch wrong explanation validate api

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using `Elasticsearch 5.2`. I'm executing the below query against an index that has only one document

**Query:**

```
GET test/val/_validate/query?pretty&explain=true
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "alkis stackoverflow",
          "fields": [
            "name",
            "job"
          ],
          "type": "most_fields",
          "operator": "AND"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Document:**

```
PUT test/val/1
{
  "name": "alkis stackoverflow",
  "job": "developer"
}
```

The explanation of the query is

```
+(((+job:alkis +job:stackoverflow) (+name:alkis +name:stackoverflow))) #(#_type:val)
```

I read this as:
Field job must have `alkis` and `stackoverflow`
AND
Field name must have `alkis` and `stackoverflow`

This is not the case with my document though. The `AND` between the two fields is actually `OR` (as it seems from the result I'm getting)

When I change the type to `best_fields` I get

```
+(((+job:alkis +job:stackoverflow) | (+name:alkis +name:stackoverflow))) #(#_type:val)
```

Which is the correct explanation.

Is there a bug with the validate api? Have I misunderstood something? Isn't the scoring the only difference between these two types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you picked the `most_fields` type with an explicit `AND` operator, [the reasoning](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#operator-min) is that one match query is going to be generated per field and **all terms must be present in a single field** for a document to match, which is your case, i.e. both terms `alkis` and `stackoverflow` are present in the `name` field, hence why the document matches.

So in the explanation of the corresponding Lucene query, i.e.

```
+(((+job:alkis +job:stackoverflow) (+name:alkis +name:stackoverflow)))
```

when no specific operator is specified between the terms, the [default one is an OR](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)

So you need to read this as: Field `job` must have both `alkis` and `stackoverflow` **OR** field `name` must have both `alkis` and `stackoverflow`.

The AND operator that you apply only concerns all the terms in your query but in regard to a single field, it's not an AND between all fields. Said differently, your query will be executed as a two `match` queries (one per field) in a `bool/should` clause, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "match": { "job":  "alkis stackoverflow" }},
        { "match": { "name": "alkis stackoverflow" }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In summary, the `most_fields` type is most useful when querying multiple fields that contain the same text analyzed in different ways. **This is not your case** and you'd probably better be using `cross_fields` or `best_fields` depending on your use case, but certainly not `most_fields`.

**UPDATE**

When using the `best_fields` type, ES generates a [`dis_max` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html) instead of a `bool/should` and the `|` (which is not an OR !!) sign separates all sub-queries in a `dis_max` query.

Comment: Thank you for your help. If the default operator is `OR` why am I seeing the `|` when I use `best_fields`?

Comment: Because when using the `best_fields` type, ES generates a [`dis_max` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html) instead of a `bool/should` and the `|` (which is not an OR !!) sign separates all sub-queries in a `dis_max` query.

Comment: It seems that I have some reading to do. Thank you for your help. Can you please add this comment to your answer. This is what solved my question.